# Postgresql how to use union for two selects in the same table?

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I have one table:

| id | created_at | author |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 02.02.2020 | manager |
| 2 | 02.02.2020 | client |
| 3 | 02.02.2020 | manager |

I want to get result like below, and date sorted:

| date | manager | client |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02.02.2020 | 2 | 1 |
| 03.02.2020 | 5 | 3 |

I tried:

```
SELECT created_at::date, count(id) AS manager FROM orders where author = 'manager' GROUP BY created_at::date
union
SELECT created_at::date, count(id) AS client FROM orders where author = 'client' GROUP BY created_at::date
```

And I got:

| date | manager |
| --- | --- |
| 03.02.2020 | 2 |
| 02.02.2020 | 5 |

Comment: The input and output data do not seem to add up.  Please fix the data.

Comment: I know, but I don't know how. In examples used two tables with the same fields, i have one table.

Comment: We can't help you without at least understanding how the data looks at start and how it looks at the end.

Comment: First table in question it is examples my data. It contains records for year, each record have author manager or client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a union, this can be done in a single query using a filtered aggregate:

```
select created_at::date, 
       count(*) filter (where author = 'manager') as managers,
       count(*) filter (where author = 'client') as clients
from orders
group by created_at::date
order by created_at::date
```

Comment: Works! Thank you!